# svg won't display in firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

Is there something wrong with this code? The picture displays fine in Safari but Firefox doesn't display anything:

```
<div id="container"><img src="picture1.svg"/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Firefox 4.0b6 or later for svg in img to work there, [here's the bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276431) if you're interested. Opera has supported svg-in-img since [version 9.5](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera95/#graphics).

Comment: I have firefox working now with this code:    <object data="picture1.svg" type="image/svg+xml">.  Of the five major browsers that just leaves IE, which I cannot for the life of me get the svg to display!

Comment: That should work just fine in IE9, but for older versions of IE you're going to need a shim like SVGWeb for example. See http://svgboilerplate.com/